# Why aren't Cabinet meeting records released after 20 years?

Tags: united-kingdom, freedom-of-information

[A page on the National Archives' website states the following](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/cabinetpapers/cabinet-gov/meetings-papers.htm):

> Records of cabinet meetings are confidential documents and only transferred to The National Archives after 30 years - the 30-year rule.

[Wikipedia mentions a "Thirty-year rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-year_rule), though claims that this has now been changed to 20 years. Why doesn't that apply in this case?

Comment: Which is "this case" you are refering to?

Comment: @SJuan76 The case of the Cabinet records (as the National Archives' page states 30 years, rather than the supposed changed period of 20 years).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### They [are](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Eliz2/6-7/51/section/3)

Well, almost. They are in the [process](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/about/our-role/transparency/20-year-rule/) of reducing the time from 30 to 20 years by doing 2 years at a time between 2013 and 2022 - right now it’s a 23 year rule.

I guess you found a webpage that hasn’t been updated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although I referenced the National Archives' page, I was originally interested due to Jacob Rees-Mogg referencing this in a recent interview where he says "what is said in Cabinet will come out in 30 years' time" ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Lf76mW0AWI), starting at roughly 7:28). Do you think this was just a mistake on his part?

Comment: I sent an enquiry to the National Archives - it is indeed an outdated page; I suppose he was mistaken.